# Acronis True Image failing to backup

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, backup, acronis

I have Acronis True Image 9.5 on Windows 2003 standard edition and it started failing to backup. 
Firstly it gave the error that it was unable to make a backup because of bad sectors on the disk. This prevented me from making full disc image backups. I then started to make backups of files and folders. Now I can't even make backups of files and folders. All scheduled backups for Acronis have the notice "no operation started"

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following

- Confirm the disk does NOT have bad sectors in Disk Management (Acronis True Image had a tendency of reporting bad sectors when there were none). You may also need to check your RAID monitor to ensure the disk is okay.
- If the disk is okay then restart the Acronis Services
- Try re-creating the backup job
- Check for updates to the software you're using
- If that doesn't work reboot the server

It should also go without saying that you should check the Acronis KB for issues like this. VSS has been known to cause issues with backups as well.

Comment: `If that doesn't work reboot the server` <-- What will rebooting do to make the problem go away (and not come back)? I know in the Windows community this is pretty much accepted as a standard (and expedient) solution to problems, but I ***HATE*** seeing "And if that doesn't work just reboot!" as part of an answer.  IMHO it's the equivalent of throwing your trash over the fence into your neighbor's yard.

Comment: i rebooted the server and managed to make a true image backup. I am now busy with setting up a new server. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Backup what you can. Boot to the Windows Server 2003 disk, load the necessary RAID drivers, enter the recovery console, run `chkdsk c: /r`

Repeat this for all other volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the bad sector issue. I'd replace the disk thats failing then worry about acronis.

Comment: Acronis can incorrectly report bad sectors on disks - that may not be his issue

Comment: Doesn't matter if its his root issue or not, Acronis thinks it is. He needs to determine whether it is or isn't then he can work on Acronis.